# replace characters in a list of strings and create all possibilities

Tags: python

Hey I encountered a new problem in my code. At one point I have a list which does look like this one. (Usually much longer but this is not import to understand the problem)

```
['-0---11-', '--1--110', '01---100', '1--101-0', '10-1-1-0']
```

At positions with a bar can either be a 0 or a 1. Now I want to know for example how many unique strings with only 3 bars left does the list represent. In the example above the last three strings already only have three bars but the first two strings have four and five bars. `'-0---11-'`can thus represent `'-0--1111','-0--1110','000--11-',....`
So my idea is basically first to create all possibilities and then search for unique ones, so that I dont overcount. My question is now how I can create all possibilities?

Edit: An other more simple example which perhaps clarify my problem. Let's say the list does look like:

```
['--11', '--10', '010-']
```

Now I want to see how many unique strings I have when I only have at max 1 bar. Each bar represents a 1 or 0 so I have to write down all possibilities. The result would be:

```
['-111', '-011', '0-11', '1-11',  '-010', '-110', '0-10', '1-10',   '010-']
```

I hope I didn't forget any possibility. Now I have to search for duplicates and want to delete them. In this example there aren't any so I am done.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question.

Comment: See [Combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) and [Khan Academy: Permutation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/probability-library/permutation-lib/v/permutation-formula).

Comment: After reading Peter Wood's suggestion, check out Python's combinations/permutations support => https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive solution like this

```
def possibilities(pattern, ndash=0):
    if ndash <= pattern.count('-'):
        if not pattern:
            yield ''
        else:
            if pattern[0] == '-' and ndash > 0:
                for subpattern in possibilities(pattern[1:], ndash - 1):
                    yield '-' + subpattern
            for subpattern in possibilities(pattern[1:], ndash):
                if pattern[0] in '0-':
                    yield '0' + subpattern
                if pattern[0] in '1-':
                    yield '1' + subpattern
```

This is a generator function, so in order to get values from it, you need to iterate over the generator.

```
>>> gen = possibilities('1----0', 3)
>>> for s in gen:
...     print s
```

Or you can just feed it to `list` to get a list of all possibilities.

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(possibilities('1----0', 3)
['1---00',
 '1---10',
 '1--0-0',
 '1--1-0',
 '1-0--0',
 '1-1--0',
 '10---0',
 '11---0']
```

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to python and this code looks advanced. Can you explain it a little bit? Also I don't know how to incorporate your solution into my code yet. `print(possibilities(mylist, 2))` just gives me `<generator object possibilities at 0x10d83dba0>`

Comment: Okay, so after some googling about generator functions I thought `for value in possibilities(mylist, 2):  print(value)` could work but it also doesn't. I am really a bit puzzled at the moment. I am sorry for that..

Comment: @HighwayJohn There was a bug, just updated it to work.